# libgdx html5 performance

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

I am developing games in libgdx for HTML5 deployment.

Even if my games are not demanding in terms of performance(g.e.tipical SNAKE game) I find very huge differences between clients connecting from different computers.

It seems the games are too senstive to hardware when deployed on browser.

My question:
I fear I am doing something wrong, or something js does not like. So I ask for general guidelines to avoid FPS drops on HTML. I'm trying to always use small resources (textures, audio, etc); Use TextureAtlas for icons ans small images.

Does anybody have some guideline or hints?
Thanks beforehand!